# Export Angular table to google sheet

Tags: javascript, angular, google-sheets

I have a requirement where I want to export my Table data from my angular app to google sheets.
I'm able to export it to csv format and download it but I'm not able to open it in google sheets.

Following is the code that downloads the csv.

```
downloadDadeFile(data, filename = 'Project Database') {
    let csvData = this.ConvertToCSVDADE(data, ['deal_id', 'project_name', 'manager_name', 'manager_id', 'operational_unit', 'project_applicability', 'reason', 'qassure_flag', 'comments']);
    let blob = new Blob(['\ufeff' + csvData], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    let dwldLink = document.createElement("a");
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let isSafariBrowser = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1;
    if (isSafariBrowser) {  //if Safari open in new window to save file with random filename.
      dwldLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    }
    debugger
    dwldLink.setAttribute("href", url);
    dwldLink.setAttribute("id", 'a');
    dwldLink.setAttribute("download", filename + ".csv");
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    window.open("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/" + a[0].getAttribute("value"), "_blank")
    dwldLink.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(dwldLink);
    dwldLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(dwldLink);
  }
```

Can Someone kindly point me in the right direction to open this in Google sheets rather than downloading it?

Comment: To view a csv in sheets, I believe you have to go through Drive first, and convert it to a google sheets file

Comment: Hey, thanks for you response. Could you please point me to the right resources for reference, I'm stuck with this for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the .csv file, you should use the Drive API to upload the file. If you want the file to be opened in Google Sheets editor,then convert it upon uploading.

Follow [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads?hl=en#import_to_google_docs_types).

#### Example using Node.js:

```js
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'My Report',
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'text/csv',
  body: fs.createReadStream('files/report.csv')
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id:', file.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm working with an angular frontend and django backend. Could you help me out with the same?

Comment: It shouldn't be much different. Angular is JavaScript based too.

Comment: I have completed it. Will write a detailed article on how to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Google sheets, you can use `=IMPORTDATA("blob:<uri_of_your_blob>")`

Comment: How to make it work with localhost? my url is blob:http://localhost:4200/fda89b61-6f32-4abb-b78f-f30e2e6fec13